# Why does the Titan-A have phaser arrays and banks?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-picard, phaser

The Titan-A has both phaser arrays and phaser banks. No other Federation ship of the era, as far as we know, has both types of weapons. The out-of-universe reason is obvious: they wanted to include design elements from the original Enterprise(s) in the Titan-A design. However, is there an in-universe reason that both types of weapons are utilized?

Comment: In case you can’t remember whether the phaser arrays are 0-indexed or 1-indexes, you can use the phaser banks instead.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite What do you mean by "0-indexed or 1-indexes?"

Comment: It's a hilarious _[citation needed]_ [programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering) joke!

Comment: Don't worry, @PaulD.Waite, that wasn't lost on everybody... I LOL'd

Comment: @FreeMan I'm truly sorry that I don't speak bot.